# How do I prevent the GET method from encoding HTML special characters in the URI?

Tags: html, forms, get, uri

I have a form using the GET method.
If values are submitted with special characters, they appear in the URI as:
?value=fudge%20and%20stuff

How do I make it clean?
I don't want to use the header function because this is happening within a page in drupal.

Comment: This behavior is by design.  You cannot circumvent it, and should not try to.

Answer (score 5):

A URL cannot contain spaces and many other "special characters", therefore they get encoded. Unfortunately there isn't a lot you can do about it. The most you could do is some JavaScript trickery in the form, but I don't think it's worth it.

Answer (score 1):

If `%20` bothers you, you can substitute (GREP replace) the + character (`?value=fudge+and+stuff`) for better readability. Otherwise there's not a lot you can do. Other "exotic" characters will be similarly escaped, and need to be.

Answer (score 0):

URL :?value=fudge%20and%20stuff

Encoded as:  `fulg< space >` and `< space >stuff`